# Deserializing cyclic JSON with only one class involved with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it possible to deserialize the following class with Jackson?

So the original version of the question wasn't entirely accurate. Here's a minimal example to reproduce the problem.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class,
  property = "id")
public class Thing {

  public Thing thing;

  @JsonCreator
  public Thing(@JsonProperty("thing") Thing thing) {
    this.thing = thing;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Thing cyclic = new Thing(null);
    cyclic.thing = cyclic;

    String serialised = mapper.writeValueAsString(cyclic);
    System.out.println(serialised);

    Thing deserialised = mapper.readerFor(Thing.class).readValue(serialised);
    System.out.println(deserialised.thing == deserialised);
  }
}
```

This causes the unresolved forward reference exception. The issue seems to be that Jackson is told to use the annotated constructor, but it can't due to the cyclic dependency.

Comment: I'm not sure Jackson can handle that out of the box (I'm ready to be proven wrong though). I'd assume that Jackson first tries to completely deserialize the object before putting it into some storage to be looked up for reference. However, since the object can't be deserialized without doing the lookup you have kind of a deadlock. So you might have to use a custom deserializer here.

Comment: which version of Jackson do you use? I tried with a version of 2.4.1 and it work fine with `@JsonIdentityInfo`.

Comment: I'm using 2.6.3. Yes, this works, my mistake. I've figured it out. Will answer this question.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to add a default constructor, and remove the `@JsonProperty` and `@JsonCreator` annotations.